# Where is a good place to put applications that come pre-compiled?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

Certain applications like Blender and Eclipse come precompiled in a tarball. Usually I put the directories in my home folder and access them from the command line. Is there a better place to put them and still adhere to POSIX standards (to a degree).

Comment: I get the feeling that POSIX standard is mostly for programs that are integrated with the rest of your system and be used by other programs. I think standalone monolithic pre-compiled user apps are better kept separated (e.g. OSX application bundles).

Comment: The only paths that POSIX dictates are `/`, `/dev`, `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty` and `/dev/console`. Did you mean the Linux [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)? That's a standard for OS vendors, not for administrators, so you don't have to follow it. Search the [tag:directory-structure] tag here, similar questions have been asked before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place for this is in `/opt` for "Add-on application software packages" - these are packages that do not come with the distribution/OS.

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES

Answer (score 3):

Often applications like that are installed into `/opt/`, for example `/opt/eclipse-3.2/`. I prefer to put them into `/usr/local/` (ex, `/usr/local/eclipse-3.2/`… But there is no particularly good reason for that.